# add multiple cards for a customer Stripe Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, stripe-payments, cakephp-2.3

I am using this library for integrating stripe into my application

https://github.com/jeremyharris/stripe

The problem I am having is each time I add a card it creates a new customer. I have tried many things, but nothing works.

Here is my code

```
        $a      = array(


            'card' => array(

                'number' => $card,
                'cvc' => $cvc,
                'exp_month' => $exp_month,
                'exp_year' => $exp_year,
                'name'=>$name,
                'customer'=>"cus_BS83zeYXseBDvG",

            )
        );
        $stripe = $this->StripeCustomer->save($a);
```

Comment: What is StripeCustomer? Is it a regular database table model? Or is it the stripe gateway?  If the gateway, it appears from the plugin docs that the save command runs an authorization and returns the results. which is an "overload" of the definition of "save", which is why the example changes the command to "charge".

Answer (score 0):

for adding multiple card to same customer you need to retrieve Customer and create new source to that..

like:

```
$customer = $this->StripeCustomer->retrieve('cus_BS83zeYXseBDvG');
$card = $customer->sources->create(array("source" => $cardToken));
```

my syntax might be wrong for cakephp because i don't know that but for stripe steps are same for multiple cards.

you can also take reference from here -
https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card

Hope this will Help.